# How to implement multi-tenant application using ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: asp.net-core, single-page-application, asp.net-core-webapi

Note: May be my question is duplicate to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43114075/how-to-implement-multi-tenant-functionality-in-asp-net-core) But I'm specific to Dot Net Core API application instead of the .net core application.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on how you want to provide multi tenantcy.

The easiest way would be to create a middleware that adds tenant information into the HttpContext based on the Host or start of path. (think of changing the connection string to the database based on hostname).

There is no out of the box implementation for this, you will have to make it in a way that fits your application.

I'd advice you though (seeing you want to go multi-tenant) also todo some research on possible cloud architectures and tools that you will need to make this all working (think of kubernetes, load-balancing/proxies, ssl certificates etc)

### Advice

I have no idea how your application looks like so we really can't give you much advice.

But what helped us alot is using `Scoped` Dependency injection for everything that is tenant (make sure you never use singletons for anything that depends on tenant information). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection

And use a Cache system like Redis to cache your Tenant specific information instead of InMemory (ofcourse you already had this problem if you'd run multiple instances)

So basically:

- Use IOC heavenly (always do)

  - Have no singletons, that contain any (tenant) state
  - To make sure you don't cache any tenant state, make all ioc registrations Either Transient or Scoped, but never singleton.
  - Dont resolve any Scoped Ioc registrations outside of a Kestrel request. (this will break your application)
- use out of process cache if you had any InMemory Cache
- Migrate all your tenant startup code into the request pipeline (or on first request of that tenant, eg: db migrations)
- Again dont use singletons.

Comment: The application has two databases, one for client and connection string details, and another for actual system.
The application is created using angular 2 and .net core web API.

It will be helpful if you have any link/steps for migrating single tenant to multi-tenant application.

Comment: @NimeshVaghasiya We recently migrated from single-tenant (also called on premise installation) to multi tenant cloud architecture. We had to change a lot but we already had implement a lot of stuff using the IOC container, which was really helpful for us.

Comment: @NimeshVaghasiya I dont think you will find any documentation on this, because your application is very specific and no one has an application like you. You should read the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/) of what is possible in dotnet. and  than decide which way you will go. You will have to build it yourself